# Как сохранить значение в переменную как в файл?

Tags: curl, php

Имеется вот такая строка на php:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "$cookie_file");
```

Хочется каким-либо образом записать полученную от сервера куку не в файл, а в память (исключить накладной расход на файл). Можно ли записать куку в переменную как в файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: (.*?);/m', curl_exec($ch), $m);
var_dump(parse_url($m[1]));
```